# How should i output my MySQL data into json in this kind format?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, json

Im not sure how to output MySQL data into formats below. (eg: timelist, usersex, userage from table users.)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
timeList = new Array(),
userSex = new Array('female','male','male'),
userAge = new Array('21','36'),
userMid = new Array('liuple','anhu');
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json_encode` to output a PHP array into JavaScript literal format.

```
<?php
    $result= mysql_query('SELECT DISTINCT something FROM sometable ORDER BY something');
    $somethings= array();
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
        $somethings[]= $row['something'];
    }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var somethings= <?php echo json_encode($somethings, JSON_HEX_TAG); ?>;
</script>
```

This gives you array literal `["anhu", "liuple"]` format rather than `new Array()`. You don't generally want to use `new Array()` today.